# Eclipse Juno p2 director cannot disable full debug output?

Tags: eclipse, p2

I'm trying to install plug-ins into the new Eclipse Juno SR1 release. Since I want to keep several Eclipse installations up to date, I'm using the command line p2 director to install a list of plug-ins:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno -installIUs org.eclipse.birt.feature.group
```

However I always get the full debug output, including httpclient.wire.content.

```
14:54:38.711 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "Content-Type: text/plain[\r][\n]"
14:54:38.712 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - << "[\r][\n]"
14:54:38.713 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - << "[0x1f]"
14:54:38.713 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - << "[0x8b]"
14:54:38.713 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - << "[0x8]"
14:54:38.713 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - << "[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x3]"
14:54:38.714 [Worker-1] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - << "u[0x8f]1O[0xc3]0[0x10][0x85][0xf7][0xfc][0x8a][0x87]:t[0xa9],[0x92]J[0x8]*[0xca][0x4];[0x12][0x95]XX[0x8e][0xfa]J[0xc][0x8e]/[0xb2][0xaf][0xa5][0xfd][0xf7]\[0x92]V[0xb0][0xb0][0xd8][0xd2][0xf9]{[0xdf]=[0xcf][0xd0]7.$[0xcf]G[0xec]Bd[0xa8][0xa0][0xf4][0xcc][0x1e][0xda][0x86][0xf4]Q[0xb0][0xef]]5[0xc3]sd*[0x8c]$jDKj[0x7][0xe3]@q[0xcf][0x5]![\r]l[0x99][0xe2][0x9e][0x7][0xa6] s/%[0xa8][0xe4][0x13]v[0xb4][0xb5];[0xd8][0x90][0x92]7[0x97][0x1]#[[0x1c]6f[0x99][0x9e]O[0x98][0xdf]'[0xea][0xf8][0xc1][0x1d][0xbb]8[0xc7]w[0x88][0x11]Q[0xe4][0xb];[0xc9]x[0x17]m[0xc7][0x8d]g[0xe4][0x93][0xb2]y[0xcc][0xf6]wh[0xb9]Q[0xbb][0x98][\n]"
```

Is there any way to disable the output? I tried starting with

```
-vmargs -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire.header=fatal -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=fatal -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=fatal
```

And I also tried to disable debugging with an .options file in the eclipse base directory, containing the following:

```
org.eclipse.osg/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.installer/debug=false
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console/debug=false
```

But the content of the http download is still dumped into my terminal.

Comment: .options file would not help since it's normally regulates the tracing (not logging) policy. You have to know which logging framework is used to log all these messages (-> source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log formatting looks like the default pattern from Logback.  Logback defaults to a very verbose configuration if it is unable to find a configuration file.

You can override the logback configuration using the **logback.configurationFile** property, such as:

`eclipse -application ... -vmargs -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/logback.xml`

There are some example configurations listed in the [Logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)